# Can you set textbox to focus in css

Tags: css, focus, setfocus

I am exploring to see if you can set initial form textbox focus to a certain input box using css. I know how to do it JavaScript, but just searching the web and I cannot find the answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not possible

Comment: You can use "autofocus" attribute in HTML. I am not aware of any way how to achieve that purely with CSS, you need either JS or HTML.

Comment: Thank you @OndraKoupil -- I actually did not know about the `autofocus` attribute -- must have been hibernating for a few years. Appreciate the tip.

Comment: You're welcome, @H.Ferrence :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's not possible –  @bumpy

You can use "autofocus" attribute in HTML. I am not aware of any way how to achieve that purely with CSS, you need either JS or HTML. –  @OndraKoupil